# Strategy pattern elevators

Tags: java

I'm doing an application for school which consists in simulating the job of the elevators in a building using the Strategy Pattern.

So I have the class Building which has an `ArrayList` of floors and another one of elevators. each floor has a button to call an elevator and there are 4 elevators and 16 floors.

What I need to do is apply the Strategy Pattern in order to decide what elevator should move to which floor.

Any ideas of how this might work?

I've tried to create an observer for each floor so when the button was pressed, the observer was notified, but still i dont know how to make the strategy to choose wich elevator should go to each floor :S

If you need the code i'll try to translate it, I made the mistake of programming the variables on my native language, and that's not English as you can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at existing code for this.

The key here is to use a timer to simulate the actual time passing. You need to somehow get a hold of all floors whose buttons have been pressed (a List or Array or so). Every pressed button needs to know it's floor and a direction (up, down or any). If pressed from inside the elevator you get "any", if pressed outside, you get "up" or "down". Depending on this list of target floors, you can decide which floor to go to next at every instant, or after every stop, given the current floor of the elevator and it's current direction, and output "up" or "down" to target that floor.

Note that in order to avoid starvation, the elevator cannot always just target the "next" floor. Think about it.

Comment: that kinda helped. its working on a very primitive basis but at least it does something now :)